# Insert elements inside an <a> tag only with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a link:

```
<a href="#">Welcome to my webpage!</a>
```

And I would like that in screens of less than `350px` the link would be like:

```
<a href="#"><i class="material-icons">face</i></a>
```

To do that, I am using media query:

```
@media (max-width: 350px){
}
```

but I do not know how to insert the icon inside, if it is possible.

One approach that comes to my mind is to create two `<a>` tags for each link, and show/hide them with media query but I am looking for a better way to do this.

Is it possible to do this **only** with CSS?

**Edit:** On the top of my `HTML` file I have referenced the `material-icons` library:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

I thought it could be supposed. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To the downvoters: please explain me why you are downvoting the question or if you think that I should add something more. Thanks!

Comment: Css is for styling, not for manipulating dom. You can place two links and hide the second one. Then show the second one and hide the first one for desired resolution.

Comment: Hiding/showing the element(s) until you're at the 350px threshold is the best way to do this. You can maybe do this with jQuery, but it makes little sense to create/remove a bunch of icons to the dom whenever that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit the DOM with CSS, but you can show and hide elements like so.

```css
a i{
  display:none;  
}
@media (max-width: 350px){
  a span{
    display:none;
  }
  a i{
    display:block;  
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Welcome to my webpage!</span><i class="material-icons">face</i></a>
```

Comment: yeah that's the best way of doing it actually.

Comment: Thank you! I thought it could be a better approach to do this but I could see that there is not. Thanks for clarify that you cannot modify the DOM with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to dispense with the `<i>` icon altogether and to put the icon info in the `a::before` on smaller windows instead.

```css
@media (max-width: 350px){
  a::before{
    content:url(http://lorempixel.com/16/16);
  }
  a span {display:none}
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Welcome to my webpage!</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<i class="material-icons">face</i>` is not an icon. It is some italic text.

You might have some CSS that adds an icon to that element.

Move that CSS inside your media query.

Comment: Yes, I have the `material-icons` link referenced on the top of my html file. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score -1):

Use CSS `content` property, just like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/gqvrpxw5/

Comment: The question is asking about adding elements, not text.

Comment: @Quentin But you can also use `content` to add imagery; see my own answer.